# Custom color palette with geoplot python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, geoplot

Trying to use a color palette set by work style guidelines in making a map. I successfully made the palette with seaborn

```
detcity =["#004445", "#279989", "#9FD5B3", "#FEB70D", "#18252A", "#F2F2F2"]
detcity = sns.color_palette(detcity)
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(detcity))
```

[image: color palette]

I can't figure out how to change the palette in geoplot successfully, here is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (30,30))
gplt.pointplot(
    geo_duplex,
    hue='Close_Year',
    legend = True,
    ax=ax
)

xlim = (-83.2,  -82.9)
ylim = (42.25, 42.45)

ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs=crs)
```

here is my output, in the default color palette not the color palette i created... most things i have tried to assign the color palette have resulted in an error message
[image: map]